# Objective C - Cast operator int to nsstring

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsstring, int

This is a correct usage of the cast operator in objective c:

```
//casting an int to float
int a = 1;
float b = (float) a;
```

Why I can't cast an int to nsstring with the following:

```
int a = 1;
NSString *c = (NSString *)a; 

//I receive the error : "cast of 'int' to 'nsstring' is disallowed with ARC"
```

What's conceptually wrong in doing the above?

P.S. I already know I should use "c= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",a];"!

Comment: simply it is the way/syntax the compiler support or provide.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this:

```
int a = 1;
NSString *c = (NSString*)a;
```

because you are creating an `NSString` pointer that points to memory address 0x1. When you try to use ("dereference") the `NSString` pointer `c`, you are attempting to access memory that is not yours and a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) will occur.

**EDIT:**
[Obligatory link to a good article on pointer basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/).

Comment: Furthermore, ARC causes a compiler error at this point because it does not understand how to handle seeing a pointer to a primitive value and then suddenly being told that it's actually a pointer to an object. AKA ARC doesn't know if it can call retain/release on it or not, or if it even needs to keep track of it. Without ARC, your code would compile fine, however you would crash for the reasons above.

Comment: @inspector-g could you please explain..I don't have it clear =)

Comment: It's crucial to understand pointer basics and the difference between an object and a pointer to an object. If you haven't read that link, you really should. `NSString* c` will point to (or **reference**) a memory address that holds an `NSString` object. When you use the variable `c`, the memory address needs to be **dereferenced** to access the real `NSString` object. Setting `c` to `(NSString*)a`, where `a` is 1, causes `c` to point to memory address `0x1`. The problem is that you never put an `NSString` at memory address `0x1`, and even worse you don't "own" whatever is actually at `0x1`!

Comment: Trying to dereference what is at `0x1` will cause a crash, and the compiler is basically being friendly and trying to stop you from making this mistake (which @JackLawrence mentioned). The only way to make objects in Objective-C is to use the `alloc` and `init` paradigm (or helpers like `NSString stringWithFormat:`, which just do some `alloc` and `init` stuff underneath anyway). Casting an `int` to an `NSString*` will not work because it does not cause the compiler to use the `alloc` and `init` paradigm, or a helper like `NSString stringWithFormat:`. Instead, you merely point to bad memory.